# Recommendations to reduce table rows

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm looking for some recommendations when dealing with tables with large number of rows.

I have a table which has around 1.5 BILLION rows. Assuming there is a column `ref_id`. There could be 300K rows which belong to `ref_id = 123` and after one point (this is application logic), I never need to filter for `ref_id = 123`.

I am thinking of periodically moving records which I identify as *no longer needed* into another table (let's call it `archived_data`). I will only ever go there in case someone really needs historical data.

Is this "moving to another table" have any significance overall in performance? Or is there any other aspect I should be pursuing like checking indexes etc?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Hardware 1.5 Billion rows itself does not seem problematic. Archiving old data is usually a good idea.

If you're 100% sure that you do not need the data you can even dump it, compress it and save it somewhere safe (e.g. external hard-drive).

There are also some other ideas like partitioning or sharding that you can read up here:
[Best Practices to archive or remove old data in SQL Server 2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/325552/best-practices-to-archive-or-remove-old-data-in-sql-server-2012)

Index maintenance might also improve the performance of the DB: [Reorganize and Rebuild Indexes, Pros and Cons?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130878/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 0):

The indexes on this table are likely B-Trees. So they have a certain depth depending on the size of the key(s) and the number of rows. Reduce the number of rows and you *may* reduce the index depth.

Depth reduction will mean each key lookup has fewer hops to get from BTree root to leaf node. A given memory can hold a larger fraction of all index pages. These both make queries faster.

I say "may" because the depth is logarithmic in row count. So the 1.2B rows remaining may still need an index just as deep as the 1.5B rows do, only with the root node being slightly less full.

Secondly, if the archived rows are scattered throughout the table archiving them will allow each page to contain more of the useful rows. So each IO can service more queries, on average, improving performance.

Likely you will have to rebuild the table (or equivalent operation) before you see any benefit. This will require significant time and workspace on disk.